# Problems with event_loops in Python 3.10

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, binance, python-3.10

I try to get data from the Binance Websocket. With python 3.9 as Interpreter it runs fine, but with 3.10 it gives me errors :(

Here is the code:

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager


async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    # start any sockets here, i.e a trade socket
    ts = bm.trade_socket('BNBBTC')
    # then start receiving messages
    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I get this error:

```
DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

I use PyCharm as IDE.

Anyone there who can help me, please?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop

Comment: sorry but I don't get it how to fix this

Answer (score 10):

This is a deprecation warning, that means the behaviour of the function [`get_event_loop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) you called will soon change, in that it will no longer create a new event loop, but rather raise `RuntimeError` like [`get_running_loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop). From the looks of it the intended way is to create a new event loop explicitly rather than implicitly.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I am not sure if `asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)` is actually necessary.

Comment: `get_event_loop` itself isn't deprecated. The deprecation applies to calling it when no loop is running. In a future version of Python doing so will raise a `RuntimeError`.

Comment: That's true, I will fix the wording.

Comment: `asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)` is not necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended api for running even loop is [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) (introduced in Python 3.7).

The example can be modified to adopt it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: but if I do so in a other script I will get what I want but then I get RuntimError: Event loop is closed